# CSS max-height not being applied to image tag

Tags: html, css, mediawiki

I have the following piece of code:

```
.goplots {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        max-height: 50px;
        float: left;
}
```

and this HTML code mixted with a MediaWiki image:

```
<div class="goplots">
[[File:{{PAGENAME}}-CC.png|Cellular components]]
</div>
```

The problem is that the image is resized only when modifying the `width` value. It does not apply the `height` or `max-height`. I tried everything without success. What is going on?

Comment: Do you mean altering the width value using the MW syntax (`[[File:{{PAGENAME}}-CC.png|50px]]`) or using css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
.goplots img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

You need to apply `max-height` to the contained `img` as well, this will make it shrink in height if necessary while keeping its proportions to fit in its container `.goplots`.